# jquery datepicker parse date wildcard

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, parsing, datepicker, wildcard

I'm looking for the right wildcard character to use with jquery.datepicker.parseDate() in the [doc](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate)
it says to use '...' for literal text and also "anything else - literal text". The problem comes when it hits the 'th', 'rd', 'nd', or 'st' that comes after the day number.

I have tried

```
$.datepicker.parseDate('M d... 2012', 'Jun 28th, 2012');
```

and it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: with PHP's date function the character for the ordinal suffix is 'S'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can't do this with `parseDate`, see [Adding "st, nd, rd, th" to jquery datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199204/adding-st-nd-rd-th-to-jquery-datepicker) and the following pull request to add such functionality - https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/pull/438.

I would recommend removing 'st', 'rd', 'nd', and 'th' from the end of the day before calling `parseDate` and then using this.

```
$.datepicker.parseDate('M dd yy', 'Jun 28th 2012');
```

While not ideal this will work too.

```
var myDate;

try {
    myDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('M ddth yy', 'Jun 28th 2012');
} catch (e) {}
try {
    myDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('M ddst yy', 'Jun 28th 2012');
} catch (e) {}
try {
    myDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('M ddrd yy', 'Jun 28th 2012');
} catch (e) {}
try {
    myDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('M ddnd yy', 'Jun 28th 2012');
} catch (e) {}
```

Comment: What is the point of parsing 'M ddst yy' (2nd try) while 'M ddth yy' (1st try) is already correct?