# Format jQuery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding “st, nd, rd, th” to jquery datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199204/adding-st-nd-rd-th-to-jquery-datepicker)

I'm currently using this code:

`$("input[name=date]").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd MM" });`

Which saves the date as `22 November` for example. I need to put something in place that would save it as `22nd November` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try tbis,

```
$("input[name=date]").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd MM",
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var dateArr = dateText.split(' ')
        var suffix = "";
        switch(inst.selectedDay) {
            case '1': case '21': case '31': suffix = 'st'; break;
            case '2': case '22': suffix = 'nd'; break;
            case '3': case '23': suffix = 'rd'; break;
            default: suffix = 'th';
        }

        $("input[name=date]").val(dateArr[0] + suffix +' '+ dateArr[1]);
    }

});
```

​

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/nmtcj/2/