# Adding st, th, rd to jQuery date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I checked the other posts similar to this but I didn't get the answer I needed.

How do I add those words to the end of my numbers?

here's my jQuery code:

```
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
            "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
        var dayNames= ["Sunday,","Monday,","Tuesday,","Wednesday,","Thursday,","Friday,","Saturday,"]

        var newDate = new Date();
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate());    
        $('#the-date').html(dayNames[newDate.getDay()] + " " + monthNames[newDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + newDate.getDate() + ' ' );
```

Comment: Did you see [this question and its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627308/add-st-nd-rd-and-th-ordinal-suffix-to-a-number)? It seems to be just what you need.

Comment: I did but not sure which one I should use..

Comment: Although this [function](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/ordinal-number-in-javascript-1st-2nd-3rd-4th-29259) from one of the answers looks pretty nice

Comment: Just use the function from the accepted answer.

Comment: Could you please show me how to combine that code and my code?

Answer (score 0):

moment.js is great for working with dates and offers this via [format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). For example:

```
moment().format("MMM Do YY"); // May 20th 16
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199204/adding-st-nd-rd-th-to-jquery-datepicker):

```
var suffix = "";
switch(inst.selectedDay) {
    case '1': case '21': case '31': suffix = 'st'; break;
    case '2': case '22': suffix = 'nd'; break;
    case '3': case '23': suffix = 'rd'; break;
    default: suffix = 'th';
}
```

Add in like this:

```
// below `newDate.setDate` line
var dateNumber = newData.getDate();
var suffix = "";
switch(dateNumber) {
    case '1': case '21': case '31': suffix = 'st'; break;
    case '2': case '22': suffix = 'nd'; break;
    case '3': case '23': suffix = 'rd'; break;
    default: suffix = 'th';
}
$('#the-date').html(dayNames[newDate.getDay()] + " " + monthNames[newDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + dateNumber + suffix + ' ' );
```

Comment: And if the strings in the cases don't work, use ints: `case 1: case 21: case 31:` etc. (the same as the code above, just without the quotations surrounding the numbers.